# Perl parallel programming

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, fork, wait, children

I'm not very expert with Perl, so I preferred to ask you.
I have to launch two precess contemporary and wait them and I've done like this:

```
use Parallel::ForkManager;

for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
{
  $pm->start and next;
  @args = ("python", "myprogram");
  push(@args,split(/ +/, $param)); 
  system(@args) == 0 or die "system @args failed: $?";
  $pm->finish;
}

$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Is that correct or there is a better way to do it? Is it correct to use `system` with parallel?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's ok to use both `system` and `backticks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended use of P::FM is to limit the number of children, but it will indeed work well for you here. A few nitpicks:

1. There's a slight bug in your error reporting. Specifically, it could give you useless information. Change

   ```
   die "system @args failed: $?";
   ```

   to

   ```
   die "system @args failed: ".($? == -1 ? $! : $?)."\n";
   ```
2. Needless use of overly-complex C-style for loop. I'd change

   ```
   for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++)
   ```

   to

   ```
   for my $i (0..1)
   ```
3. It looks like you're trying to parse a command line to avoid calling a shell, when you could simply call the shell.

   ```
   @args = ("python", "myprogram");
   push(@args,split(/ +/, $param)); 
   system(@args)
   ```

   could be written as

   ```
   system("python myprogram $param")
   ```